# Gradle wrapper NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradlew

When I run ./gradlew I get

> Exception in thread "main" **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError**:
>   org/gradle/wrapper/GradleWrapperMain Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)   at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)

My project compiles using the Android Studio but stopped compiling from command line

Comment: A way to bypass it meanwhile:
Installed gradle using `brew install gradle`
then run `gradle build` instead of `./gradlew`

Comment: Have You tried running `./gradlew build`?

Comment: Try using Gal's technique for downloading Gradle and run `gradle wrapper` to regenerate your wrapper. Perhaps something got mistakenly deleted.

Comment: Make sure you have `gradle-wrapper.jar` in `gradle/wrapper/` under the project dir.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Probably something went bad. The solution:

1. Install gradle: `brew install gradle`
2. Regenerate wrapper: `gradle wrapper`

Comment: @MohammadRafayAleem if thisworked then you may wanna accept it as "Accepted Answer" by clicking the thick

Answer (score 12):

See https://github.com/drone/drone/issues/256

My `.gitignore` had `*.jar` in it, so I wasn't getting all the jars I needed in my repository.

Comment: Thank you, this has also been my problem. Without your hint I probably would have searched endlessly.

Comment: In this case, you might consider adding both
`*.jar` and `!gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar` to your `.gitignore` file

Answer (score 1):

I had the same, or similar, problem when trying to build my app from command line, but with an exception thrown for 'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.tools.javac.util.Context' which did not happen when building within Android Studio. I found out that AS brings along it's own JRE and I resolved the issue by setting 'JAVA_HOME' to the AS JRE path. In my case it turned into:

```
$ JAVA_HOME=/opt/android-studio/jre ./gradlew build
```

You can find this path under 'File' -> 'Project Structure' -> 'SDK Location', see screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I hit this issue when I have a directory with a ":" (no quotes, just a colon) in it.

This was on a linux machine.

Before:

"my:directory"

as in

```
/Users/me/projects/project1/my:directory/
```

then i renamed it to

```
/Users/me/projects/project1/my_directory/
```

and the error went away.